# Import from sibling directory

Tags: python, path, directory, parent, sys

I have a Python class called "ClassA" and another Python class which is supposed to import ClassA which is "ClassB". The directory structure is as follows:

```
MainDir
../Dir
..../DirA/ClassA
..../DirB/ClassB
```

How would I use `sys.path` so that ClassB can use ClassA?

Comment: It's called relative imports and has quite a bit of googleable material and SO questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You really should be using packages. Then MainDir is placed at a point in the file system on sys.path (e.g. .../site-packages), then you can say in ClassB:

```
from MainDir.Dir.DirA import ClassA # which is actually a module
```

You just have to place files named `__init__.py` in each directory to make it a package hierarchy.

Comment: I added MainDir to the sys.path and tried your solution, but it just says there is no module named MainDir.Dir.DirA, and there are __init__.pys in all directories.

Comment: Don't add MainDir, add its parent directory. If you add MainDir (if that is not the package root, that is fine), then import like `from Dir.DirA import ClassA` instead.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that "turning your code into a package" means **all of** 1) putting an `__init__.py` in the top dir of your code **and** 2) adding the parent directory of the top dir to your `PYTHONPATH` **and** 3) setting the `__package__` variable in your Python program to the name of the directory that contains `__init__.py`.  All is working now, thanks!

Comment: if ClassA.py code defines `import ClassAA` where ClassAA.py is also in DirA, then the above method fails when ClassA is imported from ClassB. What is the correct way in this situation?

Comment: @Phoenix Use a relative import `import .ClassAA`, or in ClassB `import ..DirA.ClassAA`.

Answer (score 53):

*as a literal answer to the question '**Python Import from parent directory**':*

to import 'mymodule' that is in the parent directory of your current module:

```
import os
parentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
os.sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 
import mymodule
```

**edit**
Unfortunately, the `__file__` attribute is not always set.
A more secure way to get the parentdir is through the inspect module:

```
import inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
```

Comment: Remi - Thanks for the literal answer.  I found this useful when writing test code for a python app.  I can place the test code in a subdirectory, and I can begin to put tests in place without modifying the existing project.  (In other words; converting the existing code to a module before having tests in place would be the incorrect order to do things from the perspective of managing the risk of introducing bugs to working code.)  Your method of changing the module path is handy.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [relative import](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328) (example from link, current module - `A.B.C`):

```
from . import D                 # Imports A.B.D
from .. import E                # Imports A.E
from ..F import G               # Imports A.F.G
```

Comment: @Yakattak: Yes, but they should be in a package anyway ;)

Comment: this looks like the best and simplest answer

Comment: caution: relative imports rely on `__name__` of modules, so if you ever intend to run the current module (which sets `__name__` to `__main__`), the relative imports will fail

Comment: What are the critera for calling it a package?  Just that each of the subfolders contains an __init__.py?

Comment: @Sledge It means **all three of** 1) putting an `__init__.py` in the top directory of your code **and** 2) adding the parent directory of the top dir to your `PYTHONPATH` **and** 3) setting the `__package__` variable in your Python program to the name of the directory that contains `__init__.py`.