# How do you import a module on one level higher?

Tags: python

For:

```
app/
__init__.py
abc.py
  mod/
  __init__.py
  def.py
```

How would I import abc.py from def.py?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Import from parent directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542352/python-import-from-parent-directory)

Answer (score 8):

to import module 'abc.py' that is in the parent directory of your current module:

```
import os
parentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
os.sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 
import abc
```

Answer (score 2):

in module def if you want to import say abc just do:

```
from ..abc import *
```

Note: as def is a python keyword, using that name for a module does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: I get an invalid syntax error when doing `import ..abc` and a Attempted relative import error if I try to `from ..abc import testfunc`.

Comment: The second syntax is the right one for relative imports I was a bit too fast to answer. I use it, but in deployed modules. I believe it does not work if you try to run python file directly from command line.