# What is the correct way to import top level module?

Tags: python

I want to be able to reference a top level module inside another module (one level deeper).
My solution works, but I want to know if this is the best way to do it. Please suggest for minimum **python 2.4**

In below example I want to import `base.py` in `abc.py`.

Here is a simplified directory structure -

```
- test.py
- mymodule/
    - base.py
    - __init__.py
    - meta/
        - abc.py
        - __init__.py
```

Contents of `base.py`

```
class basec1:
    def basec1f1(self):
        print "base::C1::F1() called"

class basec2:
    def basec2f1(self):
        print "base::C2::F1() called"
```

Contents of `abc.py`

```
from mymodule.base import basec1

def abcfn():
    print "abcfn() called"
    obj = basec1()
    obj.basec1f1()
```

Contents of `test.py`

```
import mymodule.meta.abc as abc

abc.abcfn()
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks good to me. You could forgo the package approach (i.e. remove the `__init__.py` file) and use [relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247535/how-do-you-import-a-module-on-one-level-higher) instead, but I honestly like your approach better.