# How to import a module from a folder next to the current folder?

Tags: python, import, module

I have checked as many SO pages as I could and tried everything I found, but none have been successful. I also checked the PEP page regarding importing and tried every example, none of which worked.

I have a tests folder with unit tests in them, and I need to import the module I want to test. The modules are in a folder called 'src' which is next to the src folder.

The folders/files look something like this:

```
Project / 
        src /
            stringbuilder.py
            __init__.py
        tests / 
            stringbuilder_test.py
            __init__.py
        main.py
        __init__.py
```

I have tried everything I could: adding `__init__.py` to every folder making it a module including the project's main folder.

```
import src.module_to_test 
from ..src.module_to_test import function_to_test
from ..src import module_to_test
```

I have tested all other combinations all of which have failed. I am starting to think there must be something wrong with either my settings or understanding-- I thought this was suppose to be simple.

If I am making any obvious errors please let me know.

```
from tests import stringbuilder
```

Error Message:

```
$ ./stringbuilder_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stringbuilder_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tests import stringbuilder
ImportError: No module named tests
```

The same error occurs for (but tests = src):

```
from src import stringbuilder
```

Comment: do you have a `__init__.py` file in that folder?

Comment: Yes, there is one in the project folder, src folder and tests folder.

Comment: could you paste the error msg? maybe it's useful.

Comment: try:  from stringbuilder_test import class(which class you need to import)

Comment: "src" or "tests"? Can you give us more details about your files and folders hierarchy?

Comment: stringbuilder is the file, stringbuilder.py located in src. The unit tests is stringbuilder_test.py located in tests. I am trying to import stringbuilder.py inside stringbuilder_test.py

Comment: Added a bit in the post to try an show the hierarchy.

Comment: have set the app in settings.py --- INSTALLED_APPS, and try: from apps.src import stringbuilder

Comment: `from tests import stringbuilder` – you just have to look at the tree structure above to see why that fails

Comment: Still no luck-- not sure where settings.py would go? If it's located outside the tests folder then the same problem would ensue, no?

Comment: Oops, it failed along with from src, and many other attempts.

Comment: What's the exact error for `from ..src import stringbuilder`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import from sibling directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542352/import-from-sibling-directory)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If scripts are executed from inside a package, then various hacks need to be employed to get the imports to work properly. Probably the most common of these is to manipulate `sys.path`:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0,
    os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

from src import stringbuilder

del sys.path[0]
```

There is no way to achieve this using normal import statements.

A generally better solution is to simply avoid running scripts inside packages altogether. Instead, put all scripts *outside* the package in a containing directory. Given that the directory of the currently running script is automatically added to the start of `sys.path`, this will guarantee that the package can be always be directly imported, no matter where the script is executed from.

So the directory structure might look something like this:

```
project /
    package /
        __init__.py
        src /
            __init__.py
            stringbuilder.py
        tests / 
            __init__.py
            stringbuilder_test.py
    main.py
    test.py
```

The `test.py` script can then import its tests like this:

```
from package.tests import stringbuilder_test
```

And `stringbuilder_test.py` can import the `src` modules like this:

```
from package.src import stringbuilder
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from folder import my_module
```

If there is a `__init__.py` file in `folder`.

Comment: This failed, it said there's no module named folder.

Comment: Er, I think you were meant to replace `folder` with name of your folder!

Answer (score -10):

Add that folder to your `PATH`.

Comment: Adding it to PYTHONPATH is slightly less dreadful but misses the point of the question. Adding to PATH won't help in the slightest.