# Failing to import a module from a different folder in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a python file with VSCode. I opened VSCode in the `Project` directory and this is the directory structure.

```
Project/ 
    src/
        a/
            b.py
        C/ 
            d.py
            __init__.py
```

The problem I have is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013170/how-to-import-a-module-from-a-folder-next-to-the-current-folder) one, however, the reported error is different. Therefor, I don't know what to do.

Inside `b.py` there is the following line

```py
form C import d
```

but when I run this I get the following error:

```
[Running] /usr/bin/python3 "... /b.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "... /b.py", line 8, in <module>
import C.d
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C'
```

What should I do?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `b.py`

Add the following

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/../Project/src/C") #here /../ denotes the full path

import d
```

Answer (score 2):

a working example for similar structure. program should runover from main.py

```
project
│
├── a
│   └── b.py
├── c
│   └── d.py
└── main.py
```

d.py
`print('d imported')`
b.py
`from c import d`
main.py
`from a import b`

`python main.py`
output
`d imported`

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

The path of folder `src` does not in the `sys.path`(PYTHONPATH).

**Solution:**

You can do this to modify the `PYTHONPATH`:

1. Add these in the settings.json file to Modify the `PYTHONPATH` in the terminal:

   **"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
   "PYTHONPATH": "xxx/site-packages"
   }**
2. Create a `.env` file under your workspace, and add these settings in it to modify the `PYTHONPATH` for the extension and debugger:

   **PYTHONPATH=xxx/site-packages**

You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) to understand the effects of these two configurations.

3. Modify it directly in the python file. Add these codes in the b.py file.

   **import sys; sys.path.append("xxx/Project/src")**