# python module importing error

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following structure:

```
AXBot:
    __init__.py
    bot.py
    util.py
    settings.py
    creator
        __init__.py
        xbot.py
```

The problem is that I cannot import the 'util' module in 'xbot.py' because python ends with 'ImportError: No module named util'... how can I solve?

PS: I am using the following code to import:

```
import util
import settings
```

Thank you.

Comment: From which directory are you running the code and how do you start it?

Comment: There is no *util* module to import. Python does only look in the modules directory and in all directories in `sys.path` for modules to import, and there simply is no module *util* in the *AXBot.creator* package. Use `import AXBot.settings as settings` or `from AXBot import settings`

Comment: but none of the answers are the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're trying to run `xbot.py`  from within the `creator` folder.

This is the output I get with `xbot.py` containing `import util`:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Python stuff\AXBot\creator>xbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Python stuff\AXBot\creator\xbot.py", line 4, in <module>
    import util
ImportError: No module named util
```

This is the output I get with `xbot.py` containing `from . import util`

```
C:\Users\Luke\Python stuff\AXBot\creator>xbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Python stuff\AXBot\creator\xbot.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import util
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I also get this latter error with `from .. import util` instead of `from . import util`.

If you're running `xbot.py` from the directory containing it, Python can't tell that it's being run inside a package hierarchy.  It thinks `xbot.py` isn't inside a package.

I replaced the line that attempted to import `util` with `from AXBot import util`, moved up a couple of directories and ran `xbot.py` using Python's `-m` command-line switch, which tells Python to run a module specified by module name instead of filename.  Note that when you use `-m`, you pass in the fully-qualified name of the module, including the package hierarchy, but you don't include the file extension `.py`, because that's not part of the name of the module:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Python stuff\AXBot\creator>cd ..\..

C:\Users\Luke\Python stuff>python -m AXBot.creator.xbot
1232
```

I got the same output if I used `import AXBot.util as util` instead of `from AXBot import util`.

(I don't have your code to run, so instead I put a variable in `util.py` and attempted to print its value from within `xbot.py`.  The value of this variable was `1232`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works! I ran the script using -m option and passing the __init__ module name. It worked.

Comment: Just a little problem: If I reference to files using only the file's name, the script cannot find that file because the working directory is not the same as script's location. How can I reference to files in script's directory?

Comment: @hkproj: in a Python script, `__file__` contains the filename of the script running.  Use `os.path.dirname` on that to get the directory your script running out of, and use `os.path.join` to append the names of your files to this directory.  See http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html.

Answer (score 2):

Use [relative importing](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328)

```
from . import util
from . import settings
```

I would recomment changing your folder hierarchy though, that looks cleaner to me. Also check your PYTHONPATH, it should normally work the way you did it.

References:

- [PEP-0328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)
- [How to import a Python class that is a directory above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above)
- [Import from parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542352/python-import-from-parent-directory)

Try to stay **away** from sys.path hacks.

Comment: tried relative importing. Python throws 'ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package'

Comment: I'm guessing you are running this from the AXBot/creator directory- that is, `python xbot.py`. Instead, use it as a package is meant to be used: run it on a script outside the AXBot directory, and do `from AXBot.creator import xbot`. Also, @tehmisvh: don't you mean `from .. import utils`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: using `..` doesn't work either.  It gives the same error as in hkproj's comment.

Comment: Read the first part of my comment: You have to use a script outside the directory, and use xbot like `from AXBot.creator import xbot`. Running `python xbot.py` will always cause that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the namespacing is incorrect. From xbot.py, try using this import command

```
from AXBot import util
from AXBot import settings
```

Comment: Are you getting an import error? Or is it just not working when you are calling functions. I need to see how you are calling the objects inside of util and settings. You might try import AXBot.util and import AXBot.settings

Answer (score 0):

where you are is the most important question! according to that, you use the `import`. please update your question