# Import all functions from a python file one layer up

Tags: python, python-import

I have the same problem [as expressed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487037/python-module-importing-error?noredirect=1&lq=1) (none of the solutions worked for me). I'll rephrase and tell you exactly where I am.

My folder structure is:

```
Mar29
     utils.py
     Subfolder
         running.py
```

Currently, I'm in the directory Mar29/Subfolder, and in the file running.py, I want to import all functions from utils.py.

Here's what I've tried at the top of running.py:

```
from .. import utils
from . import utils
from ../ import utils
import utils
from utils import *
```

The most common error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

How can I import all functions from the utils.py file?

EDIT: also tried

```
from ..utils import *
from ../utils.py import *
from ../utils import *
```

Often got an invalid syntax error.

Comment: ``import utils`` ?

Comment: That's in my list of things tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent directory of the package is not being included in sys.path for security reasons. So add it to the path manually:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'..')

import utils
```