# Relative import from Parent folder not working Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a directory called mcpy. This directory contains some modules an `__init__.py` and two directories. These are: `mcpi`, `coca_lang`. Now when I go into `coca_lang` and try to do:

```
from .. import mcpi
```

I get this error:

> Parent Module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

I am trying to import `mcpi` from inside the dir `coca_lang`. What am I doing wrong??? I am using Win 7 and `Python 3.4`

Comment: You mention you run: `from .. import mcpi` What is `...`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I looked it up and that is supposed to tell Python to look for mcpi in the parent dir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import from sibling directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542352/import-from-sibling-directory)