# How to call files from other folders in Python

Tags: python

I have a project structured like this:

```
Folder A
    Folder B
        b.py
        __init__.py
    Folder C
        c.py
        __init__.py
__init__.py
```

I want to import `c.py` from `b.py`, is there any way I can do this without:

- Moving any of the files
- Using absolute paths ("C\Users...c.py")

Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import from sibling directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542352/import-from-sibling-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is part of a larger project. You should run `python <script name>` from the parent directory of `Folder A`. Then you can do

```
import A.C.c
```

or

```
from A.C import c
```

Comment: Yeah but that would mean moving `b.py` to the parent directory which Im trying to avoid.

Comment: @guppythegod You can use the directory structure from your original question. Are you running `b.py` directly or is it imported from another script file?

Comment: it eventually will be run from another file, but right now Im running the file by itself (for testing) and doing something like `from Folder A.Folder C import c` doesnt work

Comment: How do you run `b.py`?

Comment: `python b.py` from its directory