# Python package cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have a Python module called `util`. I would like to import a script in this package `_util.py` from another script in `scripts` folder.

Even if the `util` package has an empty `__init__.py` file it does not appear as a Python package but a normal directory, without the small dot on folder image.

[image: code structure]

How can I import this module?

Comment: ideally it should be

``` from util import _util ```

Comment: How are you trying to import it? Is there any class inside _util.py?

Comment: there is no class in _util.py. I am trying to import it as "from util import _util" in scripts folder

Comment: First, does `import util` work from you current script? If it does not that means that the folder containing util is not is `sys.path`.

Comment: This sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542352/import-from-sibling-directory ... unless your issue is the IDE not detecting that `util` is a package even after adding `__init__.py`

Comment: I guess the problem is the package is not detected as a package, because I get the following error when I try the suggested solution "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"

Comment: Can you add what version of Python you're using to your question? Additionally, please add how you're importing the module to the question; I see you've answered in a comment, but adding to the question will allow for greater visibility to other users who might not read the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A preliminary answer to your question is that modules or methods beginning with underscores are [meant to be used internally](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

- `_my_method()` should only be referenced from within the **module** holding it
- `_my_module()` should only be referenced from within the **package** holding it

That being said, this convention is meant to be a *hint* to other developers, not a strict prohibition. Perhaps the first step you can take to solve the import issue is to rename `_util.py` to `util.py` and proceed from there.