# Import function from sibling directory (__init__ files does not work)

Tags: python, python-import

I am having the same question as [Import from sibling directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542352/import-from-sibling-directory) but, the idea of having `__init__` files does not solve it.

So far I have the following structure:

```
main/
│   └── __init__.py
├── DirA/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── func_A.py
├── DirB/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── func_B.py
```

(all `__init__` are empty)

I just want to use `func_A` in `func_B` - see below for the different errors when the lines are written in `func_B`:

```
from ..DirA import func_A #ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
from main.DirA import func_A #ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
from .DirA import func_A #ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
from DirA import func_A #ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func_A'
```

I have tried running `func_B` within `dirB` and in `main` but it does not work.

Comment: you must add the parent of the main directory to your PYTHONPATH (or write a setup.py and install your package).

Comment: It should not be necessary to add it to PYTHONPATH IMO

Comment: it's not, you can write a setup.py file and install your package.

Answer (score 0):

Try from `from DirA import func_A`

Comment: That is tried aswell - just forgot to add it to the lists (done now)

Comment: And where is the file that you are trying to import it in located?

Comment: That should be explained in the graph above

Comment: I mean the file that you are importin it in, like you have a file that you are located in and you are trying to import the functions in that file. Where is it located? I don't see that in the graph above